# Custom form validation is not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to create a custom form validation like in [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/) tutorial. To do things the "clean" way, I tried to include my `js` file from my module but it doesn't seem to be working.

`app\code\local\Jurgis\Validationenable\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Jurgis_Validationenable>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Jurgis_Validationenable>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
                <Jurgis_Validationenable>
                    <file>layout.xml</file>
                </Jurgis_Validationenable>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app\code\local\Jurgis\Validationenable\etc\layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>Jurgis_Validation.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

it works if I straight up include it in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`.

**edit**

It is still not working when I try to enable the layout through my module. My code: (The `.js` file is still in the same location)

`app\code\local\Jurgis\Validationenable\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jurgis_Validationenable>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Jurgis_Validationenable>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Jurgis_Validationenable>
                <class>Jurgis_Validationenable_Helper</class>
            </Jurgis_Validationenable>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Jurgis_Validationenable>
                    <file>Jurgis_Validationenable.xml</file>
                </Jurgis_Validationenable>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Jurgis_Validationenable>
                    <files>
                        <default>Jurgis_Validationenable.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Jurgis_Validationenable>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\Jurgis_Validationenable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>Jurgis_Validation.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

`js\Jurgis_Validation.js`

Comment: What is the location path of your .js file?

Comment: added in the edit

Comment: Can you check if your file is being included in your page source?

Comment: your layout and js file name should be in small case only

Comment: it definitely is included in page source, because if I include the js file directly in page.xml everything works

Comment: Changed names to lowercase, still nothing

Comment: Can you make sure your module is enabled in **app/etc/modules/Jurgis_Validationenable.xml** file. Try refreshing your cache too.

Comment: It is, I checked in System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced

Comment: not only the file names you also have to change them where they are declared

Comment: I just tried including just the `layout` tag in another modules `config.xml` and my validation worked. What could be the reason why it doesn't work in this new module if it is enabled?

Comment: Your code is correct. I have used the same in my local machine and everything is working as expected without any issues. Can you share your app/etc/modules/Jurgis_Validationenable.xml file?

Comment: Oh my... You are right, the problem was there... out of all the places.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say, you want to do things clean ! so:

`app/code/local/Jurgis/Validationenable/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jurgis_Validationenable>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Jurgis_Validationenable>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <jurgis_validationenable>
                <class>Jurgis_Validationenable_Helper</class>
            </jurgis_validationenable>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <jurgis_validationenable>
                    <file>jurgis_validationenable.xml</file>
                </jurgis_validationenable>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Jurgis_Validationenable>
                    <files>
                        <default>Jurgis_Validationenable.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Jurgis_Validationenable>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Jurgis/Validationenable/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

class Jurgis_Validationenable_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

`app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{yourTheme}/layout/jurgis_validationenable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>Jurgis_Validation.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Is the Helper and `.csv` file necessary entirely for translation purposes of the error message, or is there a different reason i'm not aware of?

Comment: If you want to do your module properlly  you should add them, the helper is for translations methods etc. .. the csv for translating your fields.

Comment: You're welcome. If that what you need, please accept the answer.

Comment: Sure, but I'm trying to get it working now, but something doesnt seem to work... I will post my code shortly.

Comment: My bad, everything works!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to add layout updates for frontend, your `config.xml` should look like this:

```
<config>
    ------------------
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <add_an_unique_name>
                   <file>layout.xml</file>
                </add_an_unique_name>
            </updates>
        </layout>            
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Next, you should place `layout.xml` in your theme path under the `layout` folder: `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout/layout.xml`. Also you could place it, for example, under the `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/` path, Magento will find it using the fallback system.